# Docker image for aspNet core hangs on windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, deployment, visual-studio-code

I am trying to build a docker image for aspnet core on windows(which eventually I intend to deploy on an ubuntu box). 
I am following the sample "as is" given in following link:

[deploy aspet core on linux using docker container](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-deploy-asp-net-core-on-linux-with-docker)

Problem appears when I try building docker image using following command given in tutorial: 

`docker build -t mydemos:aspnetcorehelloworld .`

**It hangs after completing *step 4* called *RUN dotnet restore***

Docker output screen looks like this:

[image]

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I could figure that out. I had to do followings:

1.) **upgrade** the *docker command tool*(yes, I am working on windows 7) to *1.12.2* (version that's being referred to in tutorial I was following, given in my question) and

2.) **also upgraded** *Oracle Virtual Box* to version *5.1.8*.

Done that, it worked!!! Thanks anyway!